# How to iterate java ArrayList object using for-each in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, apache-fop

I am facing an issue in iterating java arraylist object using for-each in XSLT.

below is the code I am using for iteration. **$dtoList** is having ArrayList object.

```
<xsl:for-each  select="$dtoList">
                                <xsl:variable name="dto" select="." />

                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border="solid 1px black">
                                            <fo:block font-weight="bold" >
                                                <xsl:value-of select="subHistory:getFieldLabel($historyInstance,$dto)"></xsl:value-of>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell padding="1mm" border="solid 1px black">
                                            <fo:block>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="subHistory:getFieldValue($historyInstance,$dto)"></xsl:value-of>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:for-each>
```

I am getting the below exception

```
ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression 'com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.ForEach@59d5a6'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
2013-06-11 12:33:38,254 ERROR [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] (HistoryBean.java:452) - Could not compile stylesheet
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:828)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:617)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicTransformerFactory.newTransformer(WebLogicTransformerFactory.java:230)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryTransformerFactory.newTransformer(RegistryTransformerFactory.java:209)
```

any help is appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
RaoPotla

Comment: hi any update, please give some suggestions, it is the requirement to get details from the list and display.

Comment: Add the code from your `HistoryBean.java` file, line 452.  Add some of the sample data in your `ArrayList`; what Objects are being added?  Does the XSLT compile properly if your remove your `for-each` section?